# Question about equivalent metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

We say that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent iff there exist positive constants $c, k>0$ such that $cd_1(x, y)<d_2(x, y)<kd_1(x, y)$.

Let $h:(X, d)\to (Y, \rho)$ be a homeomorphism on compact metric space $(X, d)$. Take $d_0:X\times X\to [0, \infty)$ defined by $d_0(x_1, x_2)= \rho(h(x_1), h(x_2))$. Then $i_X:(X, d)\to (X, d_0)$
is a homeomorphism.

Q. Is it true that $d, d_0$ are equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y \in (X,d) $ $x\neq y$ 
$\therefore d(x,y)\neq 0 and \therefore h(x)\neq h(y)$ ,as h is homeomorphism.
$d_0(x,y)=\rho(h(x),h(y))\neq 0$
$$\therefore \frac{d(x,y)}{d_0(x,y)} =r>0$$
Let$$0<p<r<q$$
$$\therefore p.d_0(x,y)<r.d_0(x,y)<q.d_0(x,y)$$
$$\therefore p.d_0(x,y)<d(x,y)<q.d_0(x,y)$$
$\therefore  d_0 $and d  are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. Is it true that there is $p>0$ and $q>0$ such that $p< \frac{d(x, y)}{d_0(x, y)}<q$ for all $x, y\in X$ with $x\neq y$?

Comment: Yes,let the ratio be r,then being ratio of two positive numbers, r is positive.Now you can set p=r/2 and q=3r/2.

Comment: Thanks. But I think that it is not hold, for example if $X=[0, 1]$ and $d_1(x, y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2(x, y)= |\sqrt{x}- \sqrt{y}|$, then  $id:([0, 1], d_1)\to ([0, 1], d_2)$ is homeomorphism but $d_1, d_2$ is not equivalent.

Comment: Oh!sorry...I have find the wrong step in my proof...Actually in the definition of your question for equivalency of two metric, there should be two constant c,k>0,that works for all x,y...but in my proof ,we may need different p,q>0 for different x,y i.e one choice of p,q>0 may not works for all x,y